# Capturar qual unique key foi violada

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma função que faz `insert` em uma tabela. Essa tabela tem duas colunas que são únicas 'email' e 'login'. Em outras tabelas também existem `unique` keys compostas.
Dessa forma, uma exceção do tipo `UNIQUE_VIOLATION code: 23505` pode acontecer se for tentado inserir dados repetidos em qualquer uma das colunas que estejam restritas por `unique` keys.

Pergunta:

- Como faço para capturar qual das `unique` keys foram violadas, quando existir mais de uma na mesma tabela, tipo para retornar o nome dela, ou fazer algum procedimento com base nisso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a versão que estou usando é a 9.5, a solução ideal é o comando `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS`.

Exemplo:

```
create table foo (a int not null, b int not null, unique(a), unique(b));
insert into foo (a,b) values(1,1);
insert into foo (a,b) values(2,2);
create function ffoo(x integer, y integer) returns void as $$
declare
    tabela text;
    restricao text;
begin
insert into foo (a,b) values(x,y);
exception when unique_violation then
    get stacked diagnostics tabela = TABLE_NAME,
                restricao = CONSTRAINT_NAME;
    raise notice 'tabela: % ; constraint: %', tabela, restricao;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
select ffoo(2,3);
select ffoo(5,1);
```

Créditos para Euler Taveira da Comunidade PostgreSQL Brasileira (pgbr-geral@listas.postgresql.org.b)

Answer (score 1):

Quando ocorre um erro, junto do código representando o tipo do mesmo, o PostgreSQL também retorna um texto contendo mensagem de erro; no caso de constraints unique, o próprio texto da mensagem de erro contém qual constraint foi violada.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t (
    email text unique,
    login text unique
);

with d (email, login) as ( values
    ('fulano@example.com','fulano')
), e as (
    select
        exists (select 1 from t inner join d using(email)) as email,
        exists (select 1 from t inner join d using(login)) as login
), i as (
    insert into t (email, login)
    select email, login
    from d
    where not(select email or login from e)
    returning 'email inexistente' as email, 'login inexistente' as login
)
select
    case when email then 'violação de email único' else 'email inexistente' end as email,
    case when login then 'violação de login único' else 'login inexistente' end as login
from e
where email or login
union all
select email::text, login::text
from i
```

Talvez seja mais fácil parsear a mensagem de erro se o driver usado retornar a mensagem.